# React-Admin 2.4.0 Build Issues

Tags: react-admin

Is anyone else having an issue after running the following on a react-admin 2.4.0 project?

```
npm build
serve build
```

The pages have some odd formatting, as if styles are getting clobbered. It is quite unusable in my project.

I went back to 2.3.0 and all of the issues were fixed.  Before making recreating and reporting in github, I thought I would start by asking here.

[image: Not looking good!]

Comment: Does it have a link with this issue? https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/1782

Comment: Hey, that's a good lead, thanks.  I will try that and report back!